# How to JOIN two tables and get the following result using PHP and mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My classes Table data is like this

```
classes_id   classes_name
 1             Arts
 2             Commerce
 3             Science
```

And my second table (subclasses)

```
sub_classes_id   classes_id       sub_classes_name
     1               1                +2
     2               1                +3
     3               2                +2
     4               2                +3
     5               2                IMBA
     6               2                MBA
     7               3                +2
     8               3                +3
     9               3                Medical
     10              3                Engineering
```

How to get output like this: Get all subclasses name with a checkbox for that corresponding classes_name

```
Arts
   +2
   +3
Commerce
   +2
   +3
   IMBA
   MBA
```

and so on...

Comment: that's two different questions. please ask one question at a time

Comment: Have you problem to get the data in PHP or get the data from MySQL. Have you tried something?

Comment: I just like the result above. When fetching the result I got like this Arts+2
Arts+3
Commerce+2
Commerce+3
CommerceIMBA
CommerceMBA

Answer (score 0):

From SQL perspective, you seem to want a join:

```
select c.classes_name, sc.sub_classes_name
from classes c
inner join subclasses sc on sc.classes_id = c.classes_id
order by c.classes_name, sc.sub_classes_name
```

This gives you all class/subclass combinations, with the associated names and properly ordered. You can then iterate through the resultset in your application and display as needed.

Comment: How to get the result like above. When fetching the result I got like this Arts+2 Arts+3 Commerce+2 Commerce+3 CommerceIMBA CommerceMBA and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Include the database config file 
include_once 'dbConfig.php'; 
 
$query = "select c.classes_name, sc.sub_classes_name, sc.sub_classes_id
from classes c
inner join subclasses sc on sc.classes_id = c.classes_id
group by c.classes_name, sc.sub_classes_name
order by c.classes_name, sc.sub_classes_name";
$result = $db->query($query);
if($result->num_rows > 0){ 
$categories = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    if(isset($row['classes_name']) && !empty($row['classes_name'])){
        if(!isset($categories[$row['classes_name']]) || !is_array($categories[$row['classes_name']])){
            $categories[$row['classes_name']] = array();
        }

        array_push($categories[$row['classes_name']], $row);
    }       
}
    foreach($categories as $category => $items){
        echo $category .'<br/>';
    foreach($items as $item){
    echo '<div class="form-check">
                <input class="form-check-input common_selector fcourse" type="checkbox" value="'.$item['sub_classes_id'].'">
                <label class="form-check-label">'.$item['sub_classes_name'].'</label>
          </div>';
        }
    }
}
?>
```